# Magento 2: memcached error "SessionHandler::read(): Unable to clear session lock record in"

Tags: magento2, memcached

I enable Memcahed cache and change app/etc/env.php to

```
array ( 
    'save' => 'memcached',
      'save_path' => '127.0.0.1:11211')
```

And now i get this error

`SessionHandler::read(): Unable to clear session lock record in`

I create session folder under var directory
and i set permission 777 to all folders 
bud error does not fixed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you had enabled the Mamcached in the past and now the server refuses to generate the new cache. Just rename the cache folder and set the appropriate permission to that folder. After that, you will the site back on air without any error.

Comment: this problem was for 7 months ago ... I hope another user to check your solution and give me  feedback to I set your answer as the accepted  answer